# Is it possible to convert a pdf obtained with density() to an ecdf?

Tags: r, kernel-smoothing, empirical-cumulative-distr-fn

Consider the following code that gives us (an estimate of) the pdf of a random variable $X$:

```
X = rnorm(100,10,1)
XDensity = density(X)
```

I want to obtain the ecdf of $X$. Of course I could just use the ecdf() function on $X$ itself, but suppose we don't have access to $X$. Instead we are given XDensity. Can we convert XDensity to an ecdf? Or course it may not be the true ecdf but it could at least serve as an estimate of it.

Is it possible to do this, can a density estimate be converted to an ecdf estimate?

Comment: See our [posts on deconvolution of densities.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=deconvolution+density)

Comment: Yes that's correct, I didn't know XDensity contains `X`. I mean when we don't have access to the data. and instead just have values such as those contained in `XDensity$x` and `XDensity$y`. Can we convert these to an ecdf somehow?

Comment: I was wrong about the earlier comment that `XDensity` contains `X`, so I had deleted it.  Yes, with some work you can convert the density back to the empirical density, whose cumulative sum is the ecdf.  The problems are that deconvolutions are unstable and the density isn't fully defined--a little bit of its tails are cut off.  The gist of it is in the line `kords <- fft(fft(y) * Conj(fft(kords)), inverse = TRUE)` near the end of the `density` function: that can be solved for `y` using `fft`, after you recreate`kords` (the kernel function).

Comment: I will look into that deconvolution approach thanks. I was also thinking that there might be a way to get an estimate of the ecdf by integrating the pdf information in `XDensity$x` and `XDensity$y`.

Comment: You can, but unless the bandwidth is much smaller than the range of the data, it's often not a good estimate because the density extends beyond the range of the original data.  Compare them graphically: `plot(ecdf(X));
lines(XDensity$x, cumsum(XDensity$y)/XDensity$y, col="Red", lwd=2)` It might look good, but then try again after generating data like `X <- c(rnorm(70), rnorm(30, 2, 1/10))`

Comment: Yes I'm not getting good results from that on the actual random variable I'm working with, I get massive blow up at the right hand side of the plot.

Comment: My real issue is I want to run a Kolmogorov–Smirnov test in R but I only have access to the information in `XDensity`. That's why I have been trying to recover an estimate of the ecdf.

Comment: That, then, is the question you *should* be asking.